# How to iterate through a NumPy array while filtering cells values by index and performing math on it

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to filter/loop and perform math within the same iteration but cant seem to find the right answer. I have a numpy array, that is size 6, 2, and consists of two values that I want to minus together, however I want the values filtered before the minus process commences.

So if the value is greater than in the other column, then the lowest value should be subtracted from the high value, and *vice versa*. Also this needs to happen in a loop which iterates through the array while performing the filtering and math.

This is my code example:

```
#minus price
print('minus price trying appending')
minus_p_orgp1 = np.append(dif_p_times1, fp, axis=0)
print(minus_p_orgp1)

for ii, vv in enumerate(minus_p_orgp1):
    print('greater')
    greater_1 = np.all(ii > 0, axis=0)
    greater_0 = np.all(ii <= 0, axis=0)
    if greater_1 < greater_0:
        iit = greater_0 - greater_1
    if greater_1 > greater_0:
        iit = greater_1 - greater_0
        print(iit, ii, vv)

ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
for i in range(len(minus_p_orgp1) - 1):
    if minus_p_orgp1[i] < minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] - minus_p_orgp1[i]
    elif minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] > minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i] - minus_p_orgp1[i + 1]
print(ssss)
```

This is a print of the array where the upper vector is def_p_time1, and lower vector is fp:

```
  minus price trying appending
[[79340.33057205 78379.24102508 72188.80527274 76557.26239563
  72857.90423589 71137.7943199 ]
 [43528.22       43705.         43931.07       44571.24
  44330.43       44465.64      ]]
```

What can I do to achieve my goal?

I have also tried to do the process with just having the array being two separate vectors with size 6, 1. But that also seems very difficult, let me know what you think.

I have also just tried this; however it just prints out zeros when running the code:

```
trii = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
print(trii)
print(minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 1)])
print('it works')
itt = minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 1)]
itt1 = minus_p_orgp1[~(trii >= 0)]
sssss = np.zeros(dif_p_times1.size - 1)
ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
for i in range(len(dif_p_times1) - 1):
    for ii in range(len(fp) - 1):
        if itt < itt1:
            sssss[i] = itt[i] + itt1[i + 1]
            ssss[i, ii] = fp[ii + 1] - dif_p_times1[i]

        elif itt > itt1:
            sssss[i] = itt[i + 1] + itt1[i]
            ssss[i, ii] = dif_p_times1[i] - fp[ii + 1]
print(sssss)

[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1]]
[63455.70703442 68744.47486851 77804.44752373 79686.34612013
 69322.78250338 83255.08459329]
it does something
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Here is a new attempt, however it still doesn't work:

```
ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
x = minus_p_orgp1[::2]
y = minus_p_orgp1[::-2]
z = ssss[::2]

for z, x, y in range(len(minus_p_orgp1) - 1):
    
    if x[i + 1] < y[i]:
        z[i] = y[i + 1] - x[i]
    elif x[i + 1] > y[i]:
        z[i] = x[i + 1] - y[i]
print(z)
```

Is there a way to iterate through multidimensional lists which has real values not created from the reshape/arrange functions and still being able to perform boolean filtering on individual cells, from where you perform a math operation?

I have looked at nditer, and numba, but all seems to do a version where they transpose the dimensions of a 2d array and reduce the values, which with real values only returned me 1 value, and not an array.

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Is the first code block working?  Could you provide a simple set of inputs so we can run this with copy-n-paste.  Show the results.  It's easier to suggest improvements when we have a clear working example to test and modify.

Comment: Why are your variables called `ssss`, `sssss`, `ii`, `trii` and so on? That's not going to help you, or anyone else, to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your first block

```
minus_p_orgp1 = np.append(dif_p_times1, fp, axis=0)
print(minus_p_orgp1)
```

looks like `minus_p_orgp1` is a (2,6) array, just a row join of the 2 arrays.

```
for ii, vv in enumerate(minus_p_orgp1):
    print('greater')
    greater_1 = np.all(ii > 0, axis=0)
    greater_0 = np.all(ii <= 0, axis=0)
    if greater_1 < greater_0:
        iit = greater_0 - greater_1
    if greater_1 > greater_0:
        iit = greater_1 - greater_0
        print(iit, ii, vv)
```

`vv` is, iteratively, the 2 rows of `minus_p_orgp1`.  `ii` is, iteratively, 0 and 1.   So this `np.all(ii>0...) business is just testing whether` ii`is 0 or`.  It sets `iit` in each loop, but doesn't save the value anywhere.  At the end of the loop it has the last value, but so what?

In the following `size` is 12 (2*6), so `ssss` in `np.zeros(11)`

But the iteration is over 2-1, i.e. it just evaluates for `i=0`:

```
ssss = np.zeros(minus_p_orgp1.size - 1)
for i in range(len(minus_p_orgp1) - 1):
    if minus_p_orgp1[i] < minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] - minus_p_orgp1[i]
    elif minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] > minus_p_orgp1[i]:
        ssss[i] = minus_p_orgp1[i] - minus_p_orgp1[i + 1]
print(ssss)
```

`minus_p_orgp1[i] < minus_p_orgp1[i]` is an array of 6 False.  I expect that to raise an `ambiguity` error when used in the `if` clause.

`minus_p_orgp1[i + 1] > minus_p_orgp1[i]` makes more sense, but still can't be used in `elif`.  Are you taking the difference across columns or rows?

The initial word description is a bit vague, but it sure sounds like you just want the positive difference between two arrays:

```
In [68]: x = np.array([1,3,2,4]); y = np.array([2,1,3,3])
In [69]: x-y
Out[69]: array([-1,  2, -1,  1])
In [70]: y-x
Out[70]: array([ 1, -2,  1, -1])
In [71]: np.abs(x-y)
Out[71]: array([1, 2, 1, 1])
```

an iterative equivalent (which would work with lists just as well):

```
In [72]: z = np.zeros(4, int)
In [73]: for i in range(4):
    ...:     if x[i]>y[i]:
    ...:         z[i] = x[i]-y[i]
    ...:     else:
    ...:         z[i] = y[i]-x[i]
    ...: 
In [74]: z
Out[74]: array([1, 2, 1, 1])
```

or simply:

```
In [75]: [abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
Out[75]: [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Well the your right about that abs calculation thats a really cool way of doing it. 
However when i did it it worked, but it didnt give me the exact amount which i expected, if i use a calculator, then i get a different result, and if have tried other numbers from the matrix too. 

also, the iterative equivalent, seems to not work, i get the same ambiguity problem as you mentioned higher up. 
Also i am looking to mostly not work with ints, in a sence, i mean it should be so that when i apply the code i dont have to change the sizes and what not when moving to new data.

Comment: And thank you so much for the insight in my code, that really helps me understand what i was doing. 

But is there a way to avoid the abs function, and possible avoid having to write the iterative int, so that it is dynamic to the size i input? 

is there yet a function that can iterate through an array, and perform filtering from those indexes, because it seems also as you mentioned that it just missunderstands my code for a boolean array.

Comment: But yes, i am trying to get the positive difference from two values.

Comment: So i found out that it might not be the abs function, but even if i just use i - j 
It is off the actually number by alittle more than 1000, which in my opinion is alot.

Is there something wrong with numpys math calculations?

Comment: The value 1 and value 2, is not the values i - therefor i goofed, and the values seen was correct.

Answer (score 0):

As per hpaulj's answer, this worked:

```
[abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```